# (A)Wait for a number of instances to raise an Event exactly once

Tags: c#, events, task-parallel-library, system.reactive

I have a List and this SomeAttachmentClass has an UploadCompleted event that is, upon calling a .Save() method, raised exactly once. That .Save() method does not block until the save and therefore upload is actually completed, but returns right away and signals its completion via said event.

Now what I want and need to do is basically wait for all the instances in the List<> to raise that event (exactly) once and only then continue.. & the question is - how would I do that most simply/elegantly?

I was thinking of using RX's FromEvent(..) in combination with .Take(1) on every instance, perform a .SelectMany() over all these per-instance streams and await that.. but I am not sure whether there's a better way out there.

Comment: You can duplicate the list, and on each event fired remove the element the raised the event from the duplicate list. when the list is empty - u'll know all items have raised the event

Answer (score 2):

This works to solve the problem - thanks to Shlomo for the starting point.

```
void Main()
{

    Func<SomeAttachment, IObservable<object>> save = sa =>
        Observable.Create<object>(o =>
        {
            var ob =
                Observable
                    .FromEventPattern<object>(
                        eh => sa.UploadCompleted += eh,
                        eh => sa.UploadCompleted -= eh)
                    .Take(1)
                    .Select(x => x.EventArgs);
            var subscription = ob.Subscribe(o);
            sa.Save();
            return subscription;
        });

    var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new SomeAttachment(i)).ToList();

    list
        .ToObservable()
        .SelectMany(o => save(o))
        .ToArray()
        .Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine("All Complete. Handling logic goes here."));
}

public class SomeAttachment
{
    private static Random random = new Random();
    private readonly int _id;
    public SomeAttachment(int id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
    }

    public async Task Save()
    {
        //await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(random.Next(1000, 3000)));
        UploadCompleted?.Invoke(this, new object());
    }

    public event EventHandler<object> UploadCompleted;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an Rx implementation. You don't need to await, Rx will do that for you. Commented out lines are for debugging/running in LinqPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new SomeAttachment(i)).ToList();

    list.ToObservable()
        .Do(sa => sa.Save())
        //.Do(sa => Console.WriteLine($"{sa.Id}: Save called"))
        .Select(sa => Observable.FromEventPattern<object>(eh => sa.UploadCompleted += eh, eh => sa.UploadCompleted -= eh))
        .SelectMany(o => o.Take(1))
        //.Do(o => Console.WriteLine($"{(o.Sender as SomeAttachment).Id}: Upload completed."))
        .All(_ => true)
        .Take(1)
        .Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine("All Complete. Handling logic goes here."));
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class SomeAttachment
{
    private static Random random = new Random();
    private readonly int _id;
    public SomeAttachment(int id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
    }

    public async Task Save()
    {

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(random.Next(1000, 3000)));
        UploadCompleted?.Invoke(this, new object());
    }

    public event EventHandler<object> UploadCompleted;

}
```

Comment: You have a race condition if `.Save()` fires the `UploadCompleted` is attached to. I think you need to attach before the `.Save()`.

Comment: Yes, if you take out the `await Task.Delay` the `"All Complete..."` message doesn't show.